# About the proof of a question that a continuous function having finite limit at infinity is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

A function $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb{R}$, and it has finite limit at infinity. Then show that the function is uniformly continuous. I'm seeking for some simple proofs. Mine is as follows, I hope that you can give me some suggestions on improving the proof!

- Say $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x) = A$. Give $\epsilon \gt 0$. Then there $\exists$ $M_1$ $\gt 0 $ such that $\forall x_1,x_2 \gt M_1, \vert{f(x_1)-f(x_2)}\vert\lt\epsilon$(This is trivial). Then we can find $\delta_1\gt0$ which satisfies the definition of uniform continuity on $(M_1,+\infty)$, since if $\vert x_1-x_2\vert\lt\delta_1$ and $x_1,x_2\gt M$, we always have $\vert{f(x_1)-f(x_2)}\vert\lt\epsilon$ .
- Similarly, if we say $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x) = B$, then we can find $M_2\gt0$ and $\delta_2\gt0$ satisfying the definition of uniform continuity on $(-\infty,-M_2)$
- Finally, think about $f$ on $[-M_2,M_1]$, since $f$ is continuous on the closed and bounded interval $[-M_2,M_1]$, then it is uniformly continuous. So we can find $\delta_3 \gt0$, for the uniform continuity on $[-M_2,M_1]$。
- Now, for $x\in \mathbb R$, we pick:$$\delta = inf\{\delta_1, \delta_2, \delta_3 \}\gt 0.$$Then, $\exists \delta \gt 0 ,s.t. \forall \epsilon \gt0,  \forall x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb R$, $$\vert{f(x_1)-f(x_2)}\vert\lt\epsilon.$$
  This finishes the proof that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R.$